# When _GatheringFuture calls set_result

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am reading the python asyncio library. The `gather` function confused me. Usually, we use it in the following way.

```
async def func(n):
   await asyncio.sleep(n)
   return n

result = await asyncio.gather(func(1), func(2)) # should be [1, 2]
```

It looks so naturally. There are two coroutines and `result` will be the list of their returns. However, I am confused by the implementation of `asyncio.gather`. See [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L840). It returns a `_GatheringFuture`.

```
outer = _GatheringFuture(children, loop=loop)
return outer
```

The `_GetheringFuture` class is not like `Task`. It does not contain logic to call `Future.set_result()` or `Future.set_execption()`, so when we write `await asyncio.gather(...)`, who sets the result/exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I see where `set_result` is called. It is inside `def _done_callback(fut)`. So each coroutine in the input will execute this callback. The last finished one will set result of the outer future, i.e., `_GatheringFuture`.